# How to extract data relationship in core data?

Tags: core-data

I have two entities: People and Network (xcdatamodeld screen - http://rghost.ru/47818182/image.png ).
In method **fetch** i extract array peoples and i want to print **network.url**.

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSFaultingMutableSet url]: unrecognized selecto
```

Code:

```
    - (IBAction)insert:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableSet* networks = [NSMutableSet set];

    // People entity
    People *people = (People *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"People" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    people.name = @"Alex";
    people.age = @23;

    // Network entity
    Network *network = (Network *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Network" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    network.url = @"http://facebook.com/alex";
    [networks addObject:network];
[people addNetwork:networks];

    // Save
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
}

- (IBAction)fetch:(id)sender
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"People"];
    NSArray *peoples = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    for (People *people in peoples)
    {
        Network *network = (Network *)people.network;
        NSLog(@"%@", network.url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"People ->> Network" is a *to-many* relationship, therefore `people.network`
is a *set* of Network objects, and not a single Network object.
The following should work:

```
for (People *people in peoples)
{
    for (Network *network in people.network)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", network.url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because its a too many relationship between people and network. so your object will return NSSet if you look at your `ManagedObject` class of `People`. so your loop should look like this.

```
for (People *people in [peoples allObjects])
{
    Network *network = (Network *)people.network;
    NSLog(@"%@", network.url);
}
```